# SQL query optimisation by replacing subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

The following query works and gives me the expected result but i'd like to optimise it.
Is there a way to avoid the subquery, using only the conditions in the main query to arrive at the same result:

```
select  trim(count(tc_grp_id)) 
from FRD_RULES_TIME 
where tc_grp_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT tc_grp_id 
     from FRD_RULES_TIME 
     where nvl(matched_alert,'N') != 'Y' 
     and tc_grp_id  like 'N%');
```

PS: In PLSQL, NVL function lets us substitute a value when a null value is encountered

Thanks for any input

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Fyi `distinct` is unecessary overhead you can remove. We have no idea what your RDBMS is or what `nvl` is

Comment: @Fyi sorry i'm a newbie! i updated my description according to what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points can help you optimize this.

1. Like @Stu pointed out, `DISTINCT` is unnecessary in `IN()` clauses.
2. `where nvl(matched_alert,'N') != 'Y'`  isn't [sargeable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean). It applies a function to a column, which defeats the use of an index.
3. `WHERE column = 'constant'` exploits an index better than `WHERE column <> 'constant'`.
4. You can simplify the logic by getting rid of the subquery.
5. `TRIM(number)` is not useful unless you *must* output the number as a text string.

Applying those principles the query is.

```sql
select  count(tc_grp_id) 
from FRD_RULES_TIME 
where (matched_alert IS NULL OR matched_alert = 'N')
  and tc_grp_id LIKE 'N%';
```

If it's still too slow, you can create a [covering index](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index) to accelerate it.

```sql
CREATE INDEX match_grp ON FRD_RULES_TIME (matched_alert, tc_grp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverting that query (with a `NOT IN` and `!=`) to its *simpler* version might look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM frd_rules_time
 WHERE    NVL (matched_alert, 'N') = 'Y'
       OR tc_grp_id NOT LIKE 'N%';
```

There's no use in trimming result of the `count` function)

---

Why? Because this is what your query (with my sample data) returns:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     frd_rules_time (tc_grp_id, matched_alert)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'ABC', 'Y' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'NXY', 'N' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'NBA', NULL FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'NDD', 'Y' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'CZY', 'N' FROM DUAL)
 13    SELECT *
 14      FROM FRD_RULES_TIME
 15     WHERE tc_grp_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT tc_grp_id
 16                               FROM FRD_RULES_TIME
 17                              WHERE     NVL (matched_alert, 'N') != 'Y'
 18                                    AND tc_grp_id LIKE 'N%')
 19  ORDER BY tc_grp_id;

TC_GRP_ID  MATCHED_ALERT
---------- ---------------
ABC        Y
CZY        N
NDD        Y

SQL>
```

while "my" query returns the same:

```
 <snip>
 13    SELECT *
 14      FROM frd_rules_time
 15     WHERE    NVL (matched_alert, 'N') = 'Y'
 16           OR tc_grp_id NOT LIKE 'N%'
 17  ORDER BY tc_grp_id;

TC_GRP_ID  MATCHED_ALERT
---------- ---------------
ABC        Y
CZY        N
NDD        Y

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you don't have indexes on MATCHED_ALERT or TC_GRP_ID:

```
SELECT COUNT(TC_GRP_ID)
  FROM FRD_RULES_TIME
 WHERE NVL(MATCHED_ALERT, 'N') = 'Y'
   AND SUBSTR(NVL(TC_GRP_ID, 'X'), 0, 1) <> 'N';
```